# Django Invalid Form, Keeping the Next Parameter

Tags: django, django-forms

How do you maintain the next parameter when returning an invalid form?

(I don't want to implement ajax yet for various reasons)

Here is the code for my view:

```
def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get('next','')
        if form.is_valid():
            #Do stuff
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to if redirect_to != '' 
                    else reverse('named_url'))
        #Next parameter lost here!!
        return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form' : form})

    else:
        return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form' : MyForm()})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass it as another value into the template context, then in the template use it as the `action` parameter in the form tag:

```
<form method="POST" action="?next={{ next }}">
```